# SQL Injection Issue -- getHibernateTemplate().delete(getObject(objectClass,objectId)) method

Tags: hibernate, final

I am fixing code for the audit report for security issue-- SQL Injection.
In my code the following method is used extensively to delete records.
The method is defined in a Base Class and is extended by every other dao level class in the module.

```
public void delete(Class objectClass, long objectId)throws DAOException{
        try{
            getHibernateTemplate().delete(getObject(objectClass,objectId));
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }
    }
```

And, the method call 
getHibernateTemplate().delete(getObject(objectClass,objectId));

is reported to be prone to SQL Injection. Reported like

"Injection of data received from servlet request ("getObject(objectClass,objectId)") to User Defined Dangerous".

How to fix the issue.
I have done sufficient homework and had already fixed some more SQL Injection issue by prepared statement in HQL.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: is reported by who? The reporter is wrong.

Comment: Nizet, dear I am not wrong. I am a java developer and the code audit report is against the PCI standard and had been done by tool for audinting the code.  and if u have the solution then tell me. and how are u saying it is wrong???????????

Comment: Please fix this ? key on your keyboard. It's wrong because there's no way to SQL inject anything with the above code. And its also wrong because I can't even understand what the quoted sentence means.

Comment: Fixed the ? key. The quoted sentence is from the code audit report performed from the client side on the whole of the module against the PCI standard for a financial sector project. It is against the line number having the syntax getHibernateTemplate().delete(getObject(objectClass,objectId));. It says the user input data can inject the query for deletion and is a malpractice and needed to be fixed. How to fix it ?

Comment: I have also printed the binding parameter details as I am using log4j for the logs to be kept in a file. From their, I found that its using the binding parameters to first select and then delete the tupple against the primary key like in a prepared statement query. And its been done by some base class of hibernate api-- The name of the class called is "public class HibernateTemplate extends HibernateAccessor implements HibernateOperations". Now the point is how to proceed to fix it or do the needful to protect it from the tool to report it in the same way.

Comment: Do tell me if you have any suggestions or previous experience in solving same type of client issue.

Comment: This line isn't vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. The only thing that might be wrong is if the objectClass comes from the browser, or if the end user is allowed to freely choose the ID of the object to delete. But at some point, you have to accept inputs from the end user. The point is that these inputs must be validated.

Comment: ya u correct. the objectClass is hard coded at the dao level and it has the name of the corresponding pojo class as i am using hibernate framework. secondly the primary key of the tuple to be deleted is no accessible to the end user as i am using jsp forms to display only the field data. selection of the tuple to be deleted is done through checkboxes or radio buttons or through some logic. so the thing is it is sql injection protected by you. okay fine.

Comment: the point is how to prevent it from getting reported by the tool as the the above method is defined in one of our class in the module and the tool is reporting it. do you have any suggestions for that. also from the logs of the binding parameters in the log4j console and in the file i will be able to prove it but getting reported the same thing again from the client side will not be a healthy stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER --  This method in itself use binding parameters and can be verified by Log4j api. I have verified the logs for the binding parameters and SQL injection for this issue is not feasible